# Efficiently accessing 2 array of structs in a loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cpu-cache

I have following 2 array of structs, and a container class:

```
[Serializable]
public struct Pointer {

    public byte State;

}

[Serializable]
public struct Data {

    public uint Hash;
    public byte SomeIndex;
    public byte SomeMoreIndex;
    public byte SomeFurtherIndex;

}

[Serializable]
public class Grid {

    public Pointer[] Cells;
    public Data[] CellData;

}
```

And I intend to loop them over as following:

```
int index = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < Cells.Length; i++) {
    if (Cells[i] != 0) {
        // access CellData[index], and do more work
        index++;
    }
}
```

I know how CPU cache miss affects performance on a basic level, so I try to access these 2 arrays in order. But my questions are:

- Since we are accessing 2 arrays interleavingly: **Does it nullify the performance benefit of sequential memory access?**
- **If not, how does CPU cache work with these sort of cases?**
- What if inside the loop, after reading `CellData[index]`, I use its `Hash` to access a `Dictionary<Hash, ItemClass>`, does it further complicate performance of the loop itself?
- I choose to split 1 struct into 2 to save some memory (and I could have used `byte[]` instead of `Pointer[]`), as the grid can be quite big and potentially sparse, is it a fair trade-off?

Comment: This sounds more like a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Could you explain how you’re saving memory by splitting structs? Otherwise it’s a complicated matter but no, using two arrays doesn’t nullify it. It may not be as effective (*may*) but there’s still cache around. But it all depends on what else is being done in the core/group of cores etc etc etc.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen `Pointer[]` is a representation of cells on grid, and cells can be empty (= 0), which means I don't need to read `Data[]`, if I put Data in the same struct as Pointer, then they are just stored as default value. Note that `Pointer[]` and `Data[]` don't have the same Length.

Comment: I think it's not hard to compare the performace between interleavingly and orderly accessing, Have you do it?

Answer (score 1):

Elements within the same 64B line will still have the caching benefits if the recurrence is fast enough (i.e. "more work" does not thrash the cache).

Elements across lines should still enjoy the benefit of HW prefetching if the arrays are on distinct pages.

Using the Hash field will create data dependency and incur a penalty of course. This is a common `A[B[i]]` problem and there are some academic prefetchers addressing it (e.g., [IMP](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2830807)), but nothing in commercial CPUs to the best of my knowledge. Existing "sequential" HW prefetching should mitigate most of it if it runs far enough ahead to prefetch the Hash data enough iterations before it's actually used, in which case the penalty will be reduced into two back-to-back L1 accesses (or whichever cache level implements that prefetcher - usually the L1 should have one).
Note that the effect on performance is not direct, since different iterations are independent, but memory latency will translate into memory BW limitation once you saturate your miss-handling buffers.